# DAX / Power BI - Count of Max

Tags: max, powerbi, dax

I have a calculated column which returns the rank of each row by date. Essentially, this column is ranking or "counting" the number of purchases a customer makes (because each time they make a new purchase, a new row is added and that row has a higher rank than their previous purchase.

```
Purchase Count = RANKX(FILTER(Purchases,Purchases[ID]=EARLIER(Purchases[ID])), Purchases[Date], ,asc)
```

Result

Note that Alison has 3 purchases and the Purchase Count column counts if it's her 1st, 2nd, or 3rd purchase by Date

[image]

What I want is a measure which will essentially count the number of maximum values per customer (which would mean 1, because there is only 1 maximum per customer), but the COUNT function will not accept the MAX function as an input. i.e. COUNT(MAXA(Purchase Count)

What I am trying to develop is something like this:

[image]

But the best I can do is this: which is just a simple count of the Purchase Count calculated column (seen above). I want the bar chart to match the "Dynamic Purchases (measure)" column below. In other words, I want the 3 on the x-axis to have a value of 1, because there is only 1 person who has made 3 purchases. I wan the 2 on the x axis to have a value of 0, because there are no customers that have made 2 purchases, and I want the 1 on the x-axis to have a value of 1, because "Billy" is the only customer that has made only 1 purchase. With a simple count, it adds 1 to each column for Alison, because she has made a 1st, 2nd, and 3rd purchase. **I ONLY WANT TO COUNT HER MAXIMUM PURCHASE**. I WANT TO IGNORE HER 1ST and 2ND PURCHASES

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might help. I derived the following table using DAX. You might then use Count(Distinct) in the visual's value selection to get what you want from it.

[image]

I quickly threw this stacked column chart together with it:

[image]

It shows: Steve has one max purchase count of 1; John and Billy both have one max purchase count of 2 each; and Alison has one max purchase count of 3.

The Count (Distinct) setting I mentioned is this:

[image]

Here's the DAX code for adding the MaxPerCustomer and CountOfMaxPerCustomerMatches columns:

```
MaxPerCustomer = if(calculate(max(Table11[Purchase Count]),filter(Table11,Table11[Name]=earlier(Table11[Name])))=Table11[Purchase Count],calculate(max(Table11[Purchase Count]),filter(Table11,Table11[Name]=earlier(Table11[Name]))),BLANK())
```

and

```
CountOfMaxPerCustomerMatches = calculate(COUNT(Table11[MaxPerCustomer]),filter(Table11,Table11[MaxPerCustomer]=EARLIER(Table11[MaxPerCustomer])))
```

**Edit addendum follows:**
*(This addendum is in response to your comment)*

You might then also create a new table from what was done above...

[image]

...using `Table = GROUPBY(Table11,Table11[MaxPerCustomer],"CountOfMaxPerCustomerMatchesGrouped",countx(CURRENTGROUP(),Table11[MaxPerCustomer]))`, which will give you this:

[image]

And then use that new table for a visual:

[image][image]

Comment: Helpful, but doesn't work when the legend is removed. I have thousands of orders. A legend wouldn't make sense at a larger scale. Also doesn't work when dates are filtered

Comment: I added another approach to my answer for you, as an addendum to the earlier answer. It uses `GROUPBY`.

Comment: Interesting method, however, apparently when you use a calculated table it doesn't recalculate when filters are applied. If you select only certain dates, it doesn't change the values (unless you've found some way to include the Date dimension that you didn't mention).

After trying out your solution, I managed to come up with a solution of my own. Because of your help I will still award you the answer, but if you're so inclined, my solution is still NOT the ideal solution. It can be found here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/74vcw3n57k87cdc/histogram%20test%20clean%20color.pbix?dl=1

Comment: I have added a green background to my solution, but the yellow/gold solution is the ideal one. I would like the chart to have an x-axis, but I couldn't figure that one out, so the next best thing is the green solution

Comment: I see what you mean about the filtering (or *not* filtering). I tried but couldn't come up with anything better than you did. I don't mind if you *don't* award the answer to me. If you don't, someone else might be more likely to provide you a better one...one that does what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came up with might not be the most elegant, but it gets around calculated columns and tables not taking slicers into consideration.

**1)** I created a table in Power BI that was just integers by using the `CALENDAR` function.

```
Counts = SELECTCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(DATE(1900, 1, 2), DATE(1900, 1, 6)), 
    "Count", DATEDIFF(DATE(1900, 1, 1), [Date], DAY)
)
```

[image: Count Table]

**2)** I crossjoined that Counts table to the original table and selected only the necessary columns.

```
PurchaseCounts = CROSSJOIN(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Purchases, 
        "Date", Purchases[Date], 
        "ID", Purchases[ID]
    ),
    Counts
)
```

[image: Crossjoin Table]

**3)** In that crossjoined table, I added the desired measure.

```
CustomerCount = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(PurchaseCounts[ID]),
    FILTER(
        GROUPBY(PurchaseCounts, 
            PurchaseCounts[ID], PurchaseCounts[Count], 
            "PurchaseCount", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), PurchaseCounts[Date])
        ),
        PurchaseCounts[Count] = [PurchaseCount]
    )
)
```

[image: Measure Formula]

**4)** I made some quick visuals and a slicer based of the crossjoined table. When filtering by date, the histogram shows the expected values.

[image: Results]